# How to use while loop in function to differentiate the number small and large in python list?

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop

I'm trying to differentiate and modify the interger list to the string which is small or large. But I have difficulties in doing while loop in python function. But by using for loop statement the code can be run. Only when I using while loop it give me an error.

```python
int_list = [1,2,3,8,0,9]
def str_replace(int_list, index = 0):
    while True:
        if int_list[index] < 5:
            int_list[index] = "small"
            index = index + 1
        else:
            int_list[index] = "large"
            index = index + 1

    return int_list

print(str_replace(int_list))
```

Then I got this error. I wonder to know what the problem with my code?

```error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wan Afifi\Desktop\Python\test_function 2.2.3.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(str_replace(int_list))
  File "C:\Users\Wan Afifi\Desktop\Python\test_function 2.2.3.py", line 5, in str_replace
    if int_list[index] < 5:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you show the code, written?

Comment: Please edit the code and error into the body of your question as text

Comment: Try adding `print(index)` at the beginning of the `while` loop. Then ask yourself: "When will the loop terminate?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use your `while True` expression if you put in a condition to break out of the loop:

```
def str_replace(int_list, index=0):
    while True:
        if int_list[index] < 5:
            int_list[index] = "small"
        else:
            int_list[index] = "large"
        index = index + 1
        if index >= len(int_list): break

    return int_list


print(str_replace(int_list))
```

With this, you get the expected results:

```
['small', 'small', 'small', 'large', 'small', 'large']
```

The condition `if index >= len(int_list): break` exist the while loop if the index is greater than the length of the list. You can also use a single index `index = index + 1` increment by putting it outside the conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in minimal code without using while loop with list comprehension.

```
int_list = [1,2,3,8,0,9]
def str_replace(int_list, index = 0):
    return ['small' if int_val < 5 else 'large' for int_val in int_list]
```

If you want use while loop only, you must break it on certain condition.

But I would suggest to go with pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop runs indefinitely since there's no `break` in the loop anywhere. The loop simply keeps incrementing `index` until it's out of bounds of the `int_list` list, hence the error. You should make `index < len(int_list)` the condition of the `while` loop instead:

```
int_list = [1,2,3,8,0,9]
def str_replace(int_list, index = 0):
    while index < len(int_list):
        if int_list[index] < 5:
            int_list[index] = "small"
            index = index + 1
        else:
            int_list[index] = "large"
            index = index + 1

    return int_list

print(str_replace(int_list))
```

This outputs:

```
['small', 'small', 'small', 'large', 'small', 'large']
```